How to get the last characters after the third "_" in Jinja
Need help to get the string after the third "_"
Example
r_a_B_TEXAS
r_asda_Bads_DALLAS
r_asda_Bads_DISNEY_LAND
rdd_asda_Bads_Florida_MIAMI_NICE

I need this output:
TEXAS
DALLAS
DISNEY_LAND
Florida_MIAMI_NICE

With split function:
hostname.split('_')[3]

I only get the third value but for DISNEY_LAND I only get DISNEY and wanna have everything DISNEY_LAND

What does this have to do with Jinja? Also, did you try to read the documentation for split?

You should be able to specify the max splits that you want to perform to accomplish this:
>>> string = "r_asda_Bads_DISNEY_LAND"
>>> string.split("_", 3)[3]
'DISNEY_LAND'

See https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split
